# How to set tool tip in Jtable row

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I am trying to set tool tip for Jtable row in rowInserted event:

```
 $('#JTable').find(".jtable tbody tr:eq(" + index + ")").css("title", 'Tooltip text');
```

But it is not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try using .attr() instead of .css()

example:

```
$('#JTable').find(".jtable tbody tr:eq(" + index + ")").attr("title", 'Tooltip text');
```

Or you can use jQuery library for some fancy look https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Hope this helps you.